# Añadir icono en una capa SymbolLayer en MapBox de Android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Estoy probando el ejemplo que ofrece el SDK de mapbox [Crear un estilo para cluster](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/create-style-clusters/)

Al mostrar las marcas de los terremotos en pantalla a mi me muestra un punto y no el marcador que se puede apreciar a la imagen del ejemplo.

```
//Creating a marker layer for single data points
SymbolLayer unclustered = new SymbolLayer("unclustered-points", "earthquakes");
unclustered.setProperties(iconImage("marker-15"));
mapboxMap.addLayer(unclustered);
```

En `iconImage("marker-15")` parece que es el lugar donde cargar el icono, pero no ser como se asigna, no acepta directamente un `drawable`

¿Cómo se personaliza un marcador en una capa symbolLayer de MapBox?

Comment: Acabo de encontrar un repositorio que engloba los ejemplos https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**

Mirando en el [repositorio de los ejemplos de MapBox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo) he extraído la solución

Se debe primero cargar los iconos que después se pueden usar en las capas.

**A partir de un drawable normal**

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(SymbolLayerActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.blue_marker_view);
```

**A partir de un drawable vectorial**
Se debe convertir el `drawable.xml` a mapa de bits `Bitmap`.

He adaptado un ejemplo que encontrado por SO

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

**Asignando icono a una capa**

Para asignar el icono a una capa de marcadores, se debe primero cargar los iconos al componente `mapBox`

```
Bitmap icon = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_place_blue_24dp);
mapboxMap.addImage("my-marker-image", icon);
```

Para luego usarlo en

```
SymbolLayer unclustered = new SymbolLayer("unclustered-points", "earthquakes");
unclustered.setProperties(iconImage("my-marker-image"));
```

Ya me salen las marcas de los terremotos en azul.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]